# Jquery autocomplete - sumbit form on select from list only

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete, submit

I dont know much about java script and jquery. I have built a form that makes you enter the phone number. Now I have included an autocomplete for the existing customers.

I use the following sumbit code on other places and it does the job quite well

```
onchange='if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }'
```

However, this time I want the site to submit the form, if an item is selected from the autocomplete list, but not if I enter an unknown number (the above code submits the form on any change)

```
<td><label for=\"cust_telsearch\"> </label><input size=30 value=\"$cust_telsearch\" name=\"cust_telsearch\" id=\"cust_telsearch\" $cust_input_lock ></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("select").on('change',function(){
  $("#form1").trigger('submit');
  return false;
});
 $("#form1").bind('submit',function(){

alert(1);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  
  <select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="1">2</option>
     <option value="1">3</option>
    </select>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag in hidden form field on select event of auto complete to 1, if value is selected from the auto complete list else 0 if not.

Based on this hidden form field, you can fire the submit only if flag is 1, else prevent form submission.

If you're using ajax, you can set the flag based on the data that is returned in the success.